# SFMC solution for sending a triggered send every day with single tracking report

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, triggered-send, email-tracking

We regularly send a single email to an audience group. It runs once a day in the morning (using data that comes from an external system) and sends to new people in a data extension, using a send log and exclusion script to stop people from receiving it twice. I feel like this is a bit of a work-around, as it basically attempts to email the entire DE every day, and exclude people if they have received it already.

It also creates a separate tracking report for every day, whereas I would like them to all accumulate in one tracking report, like journey emails do.

Without setting up a journey with just one email in it, is there a way of sending this email daily to all new people in a data extension, like triggered sends do, in an automation?

Comment: TS is not a good option for mass sends. You should go for an Email Send from Automation Studio. And if you need tracking in one place, you can query the _Sent, _Open and _Click data views, to bring all the data to one DE on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

If your source data extension has a date field that carries the date a subscriber has been added to that data extension (lets say OptInDate), you could build a filter (or a query if you have a lot of subscribers) and create a new segmented data extension that contains only the subscribers that were added since the last email was sent (yesterday).  This way you don't need to mess around with subpression lists.
Concerning the report I am not sure but maybe it would be a good option to create a campaign and build a report that summarises the campaign.